# How to hide the my app store approved app in app store?

Tags: ios, iphone, itunes

how can hide my app store approved app in app store .It's possible or not.how can i do.

Comment: Delete it in ITC. That'll do the trick.

Comment: This question is off topic, but you can change the "available from" date on your app, which will make it unavailable until that date. Just log on to itunesconnect, click on manage your apps, click on the application, and then on "rights and pricing" up to the right, and change the "Availability date". If you set this into the future, it will disappear until that date.

Comment: Delete means totally remove in ITC .i'm correct.

Comment: more details are available at Apple Documentation [UsingiTunesConnect](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppStatus.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable all countries except, e.g., St. Lucia.

Comment: It's possible again enable my app in iTunes.

Comment: After you change an app’s territory rights, it may take up to 24 hours to refresh your app’s availability in stores in all territories. so yes you can do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can just go to your app in iTC, move to 'Pricing and  Availability' (left) and choose under 'Availability' > 'Remove from sale'. Your app wil not be deleted from iTunes Connect. You can choose to make it available by selecting certain (or all) countries in the option above.